# Policy Value network predictions in Alpha Zero with ranked rewards

Tags: reinforcement-learning, monte-carlo-tree-search, alphazero, combinatorial-games

So I have been trying to implement the ranked rewards (R2) algorithm from the paper *"Ranked Reward: Enabling Self-Play Reinforcement Learning for Combinatorial Optimization"* http://arxiv.org/abs/1807.01672 The idea is to leverage the very successful 2 player setting from Alpha Zero to the single player setting for combinatorial optimization.

Instead of getting positive/negative reward for winning/losing the game against the opponent, the (single) agent here gets positive/negative reward for performing better/worse than itself in a certain percentage of previous games.

This is achieved by replacing the `final_reward` with a `ranked_reward` in the training example triplets `(state, mcts_action_probabilities, final_reward)` -> `(state, mcts_action_probabilities, ranked_reward)` where `ranked_reward = 1` if `final_reward` is larger than a certain percentile of past rewards, and -1 otherwise.

Now here is where I am stuck: replacing the `final_reward` with the `ranked_reward` in the training examples means that the neural network learns to predict the `ranked_reward` from a current state, rather than the actual game reward. On the other hand, inside the neural network guided MCTS, upon leaf expansion, the neural network is used to estimate the final reward from the leaf. But if that neural network has learned to predict only if it is going to be better or worse than itself in previous games, there is a mismatch between neural network predicted rewards and actual state rewards you get from the states during MCTS simulation (e.g. when reaching a terminal state), which - I would think - messes up the tree exploration based on the estimated rewards.

How should this be dealt with? In the paper they just state in Algorithm 1: *Perform a Monte Carlo tree search consisting of S simulations guided by fθk* but they don't mention the problem of two kinds of rewards at all. Only for the final reward at the end of the actual game (not MCTS simulation for one step) they say to convert to ranked reward.

My guess is that MCTS should be done totally in ranked_reward units, i.e. every reward returned by any state should be converted to ranked_reward inside the MCTS simulation. Only at the end of the actual played game, the final obtained state's actual final reward should be added to the buffer. In other words, evaluating the final state of a game is the only time we ever consider real final rewards rather than ranked_rewards. Is this correct?